# In linux, is it possible to check stdin to see the line that bash is running?

Tags: linux, bash, proc

When I want to know that process has been spawned by bash, I just check **ps**. But I was wondering, sometimes I launch things as

```
for x in $(somecomplextask.sh); do foo $x; done
```

I wonder, is it possible to check somewhere for the complete line with the for loop. I have the file descriptor in **/proc/.../fd/0**, but I do not know if I can use some tool to examine it, or perhaps even the content is not anymore, as bash has already read the line. And it is not written in bash_history yet.

Still, I thought it was interesting to ask.

Comment: I think  `set -x` is what you are looking for

Comment: no, set -x is useful, but I was thinking in the case when the job is running and I want to know the full command it is executing at this point.